# How to loop the same inputdialog in java but record each input in java?

Tags: java

How do I loop the same question of JOptionPane.showInputDialog but record the answers entered and display a total outside the loop?

For example:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {

    test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "nr "+ i +": enter number");
}
total = Integer.parseInt(test);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "total: " + total);
return;
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `test` you just need to add it to the previous one.
Hence change your codes to:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "nr "+ i +": enter number");
total += Integer.parseInt(test);
    }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "total: " + total);
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
int sum = 0;
//While there is nothing wrong with starting on 1 you should get used to zero index
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   try {
      sum += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "nr "+ i +": enter number"));
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "total: " + sum);
```